URL Rewriting while keeping normal parameters
I am using the following htaccess to to do url rewriting. This allows up to three levels of rewriting and works well.
But if I add parameters on the end using ? and &, these are removed when checking the GET parameters.
How would I also be able to include parameters on the end?
For example,
https://www.example.com?token=123456767&ref=12
https://www.example.com/orders?token=123456767&ref=12
https://www.example.com/orders/internal?token=123456767&ref=12
https://www.example.com/orders/internal/TRV?token=123456767&ref=12

My existing htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1&keytwo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1&keytwo=$2&keythree=$3 [L]


Add QSA flag like [L,QSA]
